# Draw the simple graph with or without Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, xy-pic, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

I am trying to recover the LaTeX code of the following graph.

[image]

I have basic knowledge of Tikz and can work this out. Instead, I am looking for ways to let the program bend the arrows automatically, but not doing manually this from modifying Bezier curves. I also wonder there may be packages that can produce the part only on the left of the equality (the two `\mathbb C`s and cycle), perhaps just in the `equation` enviroment.

Do the methods mentioned above exist? Or there are some better ways to construct the graph?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you are searching for [`tikzcd`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-cd). But there are already a lot of examples for {diagrams} or {graphs} using TikZ on this site. I would recommend to have a look at least at some of them and then [show, what you've tried](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964).

Comment: Ti*k*Z has a [`bend left/right` option](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#pgf./tikz/bend:left) that simplifies bending paths without the need to define bezier coordinates.

Comment: You can try the xymatrix shown on p.16 in https://www.jmilne.org/not/CDGuide06.pdf . Or try the picture-environment, wee. e.g. here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Picture .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: This code is written using `xy` package with the colors. It is very closer with the screenshot of the OP.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[\textcolor{-red!65!green!50}{\xymatrix{
\mathbb{C}^n \ar@/^.5pc/[r]^B
& \mathbb{C}^m \ar@/^.5pc/[l]^A}
=\begin{matrix}
\xymatrix{
U_{\circ} \ar@/^.5pc/[r]^B
& V_{\circ} \ar@/^.5pc/[l]|A}\\[.5em]
\scriptstyle\oplus\\[.5em]
\xymatrix{
U_{\bullet} \ar@/^.5pc/[r]|B
& V_{\bullet} \ar@/^.5pc/[l]^A}
\end{matrix}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Warning! This codes below are written with `xy` package format `2cell`. I put two codes: one with the tips of `TikZ` and another with the tips of `xy` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\UseTwocells
\begin{document}


\[\xymatrix{ \mathbb{C}^n & \mathbb{C}^m \ltwocell_A^B{'\phantom{\alpha}}}=\begin{matrix}
\xymatrix{U_{\circ} & V_{\circ} \ltwocell_{B}^A{'\phantom{\alpha}}}\\
\oplus\\
\xymatrix{ U_{\bullet} & V_{\bullet} \ltwocell_B^A{'\phantom{\alpha}}}
\end{matrix}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Deleting `cmtip`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\UseTwocells
\begin{document}


\[\xymatrix{ \mathbb{C}^n & \mathbb{C}^m \ltwocell_A^B{'\phantom{\alpha}}}=\begin{matrix}
\xymatrix{U_{\circ} & V_{\circ} \ltwocell_{B}^A{'\phantom{\alpha}}}\\
\oplus\\
\xymatrix{ U_{\bullet} & V_{\bullet} \ltwocell_B^A{'\phantom{\alpha}}}
\end{matrix}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your work. `xy-pic` is a new package to me and after some efforts I find it useful.

Comment: @Covariant You're welcome. :-)